# Заполнить hidden поля с помощью curl

Tags: php, html, curl, input, hidden

Натолкните, пожалуйста, на решение. Через curl отправляю post и получаю ответ от сайта. В нем есть hidden поля, которые сервер проверяет на пустоту. Получаю ответ и кладу его в iframe(себе) я заглядываю в исходник: поля с type="text" заполненные, а hidden - нет. [image: Ошибка]
Хотя через пост я отправлял все данные. Мне важно чтобы они были заполненные. Так как сервер ругается.

Как можно изменить value hidden.

Comment: Какое отношение имеет curl к заполнению какой либо страницы html? Через curl вы можете только отправлять запросы и получать ответы. По сабжу hidden поля могут быть сгенерированными js'ом или могут быть их значения сгенерированными в этом случае  curl вам никак не поможет.

Comment: А вообще не очень понятно чего вы вообще хотите.